# Write memory buffer to Zip without copies using Chilkat

Tags: c++, chilkat

I am looking into the [Chilkat Zip library](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/vcCkZipRef.htm) to dump binary data to disk for later reuse. The blobs I want to dump may be very large (10+ GiBs) so copying any of those would be a waste of time and space.

I have already found the `CkByteData::borrowData` method that allows me to let Chilkat use the buffers allocated by the application instead of copying it into an internally allocated buffer. However, when adding this `CkByteData` to a `CkZipEntry` (using `CkZipEntry::AppendData`), I notice that my application suddenly consumes twice the memory; an obvious sign that Chilkat did perform a copy after all. After `CkZip::WriteZip`, memory consumption returns back to normal.

The snippet I used for testing:

```
int main(int, char**)
{
    CkZip zip;
    zip.UnlockComponent(/* hidden */);
    zip.NewZip("data.zip");

    constexpr auto size = 20'000'000; // ~= 20 MiB
    auto data = new char[size];

    for (auto i = 0; i < size; ++i)
       data[i] = static_cast<char>(i);

    CkByteData bd;
    bd.borrowData(data, size);

    auto entry = zip.AppendNew("blob");
    entry->AppendData(bd);
    // --> Memory consumption jumps to ~40 MiB

    delete entry;

    zip.WriteZip();
    // --> Memory consumption drops to ~20 MiB

    delete[] data;
    return 0;
}
```

**My questions:**

- Is there any way to **avoid copies of my blobs when writing** them to a Zip file using Chilkat?
- Also, `CkByteData::borrowData` [only works for inputting data](http://www.chilkatforum.com/questions/9059/ckbytedataborrowdata-not-working) to Chilkat, it will not allow Chilkat to output data back to the application. So even if all copies are eliminated when writing, would it be possible to **also avoid copies when reading** the data from file?
- If copies are unavoidable, **are there any scalable workarounds** that limit the copied bytes to a fraction of the data (e.g. repeatedly add a portion of the blob to the Zip and write that to file)?

*Note: I actually do not need to compress the data (but it's a nice plus). So if a solution needs to disable compression, that is fine.*

Answer (score 1):

If the new file in the zip can be huge, the only solution would be to delete the existing entry, and then call AppendOneFileOrDir for the new file to be added.  You wouldn't want to try to read the 10GB file into memory and add it.  When you call AppendOneFileOrDir, it doesn't actually read the file into memory.  Instead it creates a zip entry that references the file (see http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/csZipEntryRef.html#prop10)  When WriteZipAndClose is called, the data to compress is streamed from the file, so it never resides completely in memory.

Comment: Thanks for answering. My problem isn't really about adding huge files to a Zip but rather adding binary data generated by my application. I have a huge buffer of binary data and want to move that to a new file in the Zip without making any copies. I don't see any ways to do that with the Chilkat library but perhaps I am overlooking some clever workaround?